# Exclude sudomain from azure ad? The Azure AD / MS account overlap issue

Tags: entra-id

I am using O365 / Outlook on my main domain `example.com`. 
I have a subdomain `intl.example.com` which is actually a separate business entity.

The intl domain configured as a self contained G Suite. The problem is that there are certain things that I'd like to send from my `sender@example.com` address to `recipient@intl.example.com`.

The problem is that it takes a Microsoft account for the recipient to sign in for these resources. When attempting to sign up I get the traditional "You can't sign up here with a work or school email address. Use a personal email, such as Gmail or Yahoo!".   These email addresses aren't part of Azure AD and never will be. Can I mark this sub domain as specifically *not* being part of Azure AD somehow? I saw some documentation relating to this issue from 2016 but nothing concrete or with a resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of playing around it appears there isn't a way to do this at current.

Adding an alias in gsuite using an external domain is a relatively painless workaround, although it does create a training issue.